# Expectation in convex hull

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\bf X$ be a random variable $ \bf X$ $:=(X_1,...,X_n)$ 
How can I show that $\mathbb{E}(X) $ lies in the convex hull of $\chi $ where $\chi $ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the values which X take? 
I don't fully understand the meaning and interpretation of the convex hull

Thankyou for your help

Comment: If by $(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$, you mean that these are the different values $X$ can take - the convex hull of a set is the space of all finite convex combinations of points in the original set. In turn, a convex combination is a sum of the form $\sum_i x_i k_i$ where $\sum k_i = 1$. Does that help?

Comment: $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ is a vector consisting of random variables $X_i$